# How to create a VS code Library Class project?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code

I am trying to follow this old [tutorial](http://simswiki.info/wiki.php?title=Sims_3:Creating_a_game_compatible_Visual_Studio_project), but I am having some trouble to adapt the settings to current VS code. Can you guys help me to setup these settings please?

I already tried creating a class library using the terminal, by typing `dotnet new classlib`, but the reference stuff is confusing me.

Comment: Why not just find a more up-to-date tutorial?

Comment: I doubt there will be a more modern one for a game that was released 15 years ago. Even the latest content I can find that is talking about creating rather than installing mods is [a YouTube video from 2022](https://youtu.be/2crAPnFtt4E), and that's still just a video of doing exactly that tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `dotnet new classlib` today, you are currently creating a [.NET 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-8/overview) project. .NET 8 is the successor of the .NET Core product family and is vastly different in terms of features, but also how the project file is organized. While in the .NET Framework projects you had a lot of references to standard libraries, which is what the tutorial tells you to remove, the new project file structure is a lot less verbose and just naming the target version your project is based on, and references are handled by the build.

Here are the links to the relevant articles for creating a project in VS Code:

- [Create a .NET class library using Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio-code)
- [Documentation on the `dotnet new` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new)
- [A list of "target framework monikers" (TFM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/frameworks) to be used with the `-f` command line argument for `dotnet new`

However I think you can't create a new .NET Framework project using the `dotnet` command. According to the command line output of `dotnet new classlib -h`, supported target frameworks are

> - net8.0
> - netstandard2.1
> - netstandard2.0
> - net7.0
> - net6.0
> - net5.0
> - netcoreapp3.1

I *can* create a .NET Framework project using [Visual Studio 2022](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) though, chosing template filter "Library" and selecting "Class library (.NET Framework)".

There I could even actually target .NET Framework 2.0. Within Visual Studio, the guide you have matches the current UI pretty well.